# coldfusion combine results from two queries

Tags: oracle, coldfusion

I have two coldfusion queries, like below which return different columns along with a date column.

```
<cfquery name="qry1" datasource="test">
select title, name, id, test_date from table1 , table2
</cfquery>

<cfquery name="qry2" datasource="test">
select headline, itemid, create_dt from table3 , table4
</cfquery>
```

I want to join the results of these two queries and in the final query need the results to be ordered by the date desc (note: date returned in the 2 queries is 2 different columns). I know there is the option of union all these two queries and I do not want to use it as it will slow down the request. Any ideas on different way to achieve this.

```
           <CFQUERY NAME="getDetails" DBTYPE="query"> 
                SELECT emp_id, url_shortcut, title, name, join_dt
                ,'' as item_id,'' as batch_id, '' as item_text
                FROM get_related_info_one
                 
                UNION ALL

                SELECT  to_number('') as emp_id,  '' as url_ shortcut,  '' as title, '' as name
                ,item_date as join_dt, item_id, batch_id, item_text 
                FROM get_related_info_two
            </CFQUERY>
```

I am getting the error:
Query Of Queries syntax error.
 Encountered "(.
 Incorrect Select Statement, 
 Expecting a 'FROM', but encountered '(' instead, 
 A select statement should have a 'FROM' construct.
Any idea what am i missing here.

Comment: i mean... anything other than making it a single trip to the db (rather than two) would likely "slow down the request", you've gotta either union them or join them, either with sql or by looping,

Comment: Actually you can't use a union query because query1 returns 4 columns and query2 returns 3.  You say you want to join the results.  In what way?

Comment: @DanBracuk sure you can, just create an alias to represent the column not in the other table

Answer (score 1):

As long as the column types are the same you can UNION them like this.

```
<cfquery name="qry1" datasource="test">
select title, name, id, test_date 
from table1 , table2
UNION
select headline, '' as name, itemid, create_dt 
from table3 , table4
ORDER BY test_date
</cfquery>
```

Comment: They are different column types getting few errors trying to resolve

Comment: You can use `cast(title as varchar)` or something similar if they are different types

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a CF-based approach (especially when using in-memory query-of-queries), Ben Nadel wrote a QueryAppend UDF.

https://www.bennadel.com/blog/114-coldfusion-queryappend-qone-qtwo.htm

I made some recent tweaks to it so that NULL dates (treated as "empty" by ColdFusion) aren't incorrectly cast.

https://gist.github.com/JamoCA/5a2adb52cbeb4e15337a7d899222072e

```
<!--- 7/5/2006 QueryAppend By Ben Nadel https://www.bennadel.com/blog/114-coldfusion-queryappend-qone-qtwo.htm
      1/5/2017 New "EmptyAsNull" option to prevent NULL values (dates & numbers) from being incorrectly recast
      to an invalid "empty string" by ColdFusion's Query-of-Queries and throwing "Error casting an object
      of type to an incompatible type" error. --->
<cffunction name="QueryAppend" access="public" returntype="void" output="false" hint="This takes two queries and appends the second one to the first one. This actually updates the first query and does not return anything.">
    <cfargument name="QueryOne" type="query" required="true">
    <cfargument name="QueryTwo" type="query" required="true">
    <cfargument name="EmptyAsNull" default="" required="false"> 
    <cfset var LOCAL = StructNew()>
    <cfset LOCAL.Columns = ListToArray(ARGUMENTS.QueryOne.ColumnList)>
    <cfset LOCAL.EmptyAsNull = 0>
    <cfif isValid("boolean", ARGUMENTS.EmptyAsNull) AND ARGUMENTS.EmptyAsNull>
        <cfset LOCAL.EmptyAsNull = 1>
    </cfif>
    <cfloop query="ARGUMENTS.QueryTwo">
        <cfset QueryAddRow(ARGUMENTS.QueryOne)>
        <cfloop ARRAY="#LOCAL.Columns#" index="LOCAL.ColumnName">
            <cfif StructKeyExists(ARGUMENTS.QueryTwo, LOCAL.ColumnName) AND (NOT LOCAL.EmptyAsNull OR LEN(ARGUMENTS.QueryTwo[LOCAL.ColumnName][ARGUMENTS.QueryTwo.CurrentRow]))>
                <cfset ARGUMENTS.QueryOne[LOCAL.ColumnName][ARGUMENTS.QueryOne.RecordCount] = ARGUMENTS.QueryTwo[LOCAL.ColumnName][ARGUMENTS.QueryTwo.CurrentRow]>
            </cfif>
        </cfloop>
    </cfloop>
    <cfreturn>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: NOTE: You may need to use aliases for your mismatched column names so that they they are consistent between both queries. I usually add `'headline' AS RecordType, Headline AS Title` and `'title' AS RecordType, Title`. If they aren't using the same name (and datatype), you won't be able to combine them.

Comment: Do you have any examples of how you invoke this function? Everything I seem to do seems to fail.

Comment: What is the fail/error message? Are the datatypes for the columns to be merged the same? I just tried a simple test by adding a duplicated query of itself & it correctly doubled the recordset. q1 = duplicate(myQuery); q2 = duplicate(myQuery); request.queryappend(q1, q2); writedump(q1);